# Как выключением Checkbutton стереть построенный график?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Написал простой код построения графиков в matplotlib с использованием tkinter. Задумано: при включении Checkbutton график строится. При выключении - стирается. Но стирание построенного графика работает не так как задумал. Подскажите, где ошибаюсь? Спасибо.

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np

def select():
    x = np.arange(0,25,0.1)
    if SIN.get() == 1:
        y = np.sin(x)
        ax.plot(x, y)
        canvasAgg.draw()
    if SIN.get() == 0: ax.clear()

    if COS.get() == 1:
        y = np.cos(x)
        ax.plot(x, y)
        canvasAgg.draw()
    if COS.get() == 0: ax.clear()

root = Tk()

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100, facecolor='white')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
canvasAgg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvasAgg.draw()
canvas = canvasAgg.get_tk_widget()
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

f1 = Frame(relief=RAISED, borderwidth=0)
f1.pack(expand=True, side=LEFT)
SIN = IntVar()
SIN_checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(f1, text = 'sin', variable = SIN, command=select)
SIN_checkbutton.pack()

f2 = Frame(relief=RAISED, borderwidth=0)
f2.pack(expand=True, side=LEFT)
COS = IntVar()
COS_checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(f2, text = 'cos', variable = COS, command=select)
COS_checkbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов: очищать ось сразу и прорисовывать только выбранные

```
def select():
    x = np.arange(0,25,0.1)
    ax.clear()
    if SIN.get():
        y = np.sin(x)
        ax.plot(x, y)
    if COS.get():
        y = np.cos(x)
        ax.plot(x, y)
    canvasAgg.draw()
```

---

второй вариант - сделать две разные оси слева и справа. Удобно для разномасштабных графиков

```
def select():
    x = np.arange(0,25,0.1)

    if SIN.get():
        y = np.sin(x)
        ax1.plot(x, y)
    else:
        ax1.clear()

    if COS.get():
        y = np.cos(x)
        ax2.plot(x, y)
    else:
        ax2.clear()
    canvasAgg.draw()

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100, facecolor='white')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Первый вариант самое то!